# What do those hosting/creating bitcoin games get from their efforts?

Tags: earnings

I'm curious why there are so many different ways to get bitcoin from games and such. What do the people that make them get from making them? Do they use my CPU time to mine?

Answer (score 0):

Ad revenue most likely. Or they install malware on your computer.

I doubt they'd be stupid enough to try to mine using your CPU.